# Quotient map with discrete fibers.

Tags: general-topology

Let us we have continuous map of topological spaces $\varphi\colon X\to Y.$

Let $\varphi$ be a quotient map with discrete fibers.

Under which assumptions $\varphi$ is closed map?

In general both $X$ and $Y$ could be neither compact nor Hausdorff.

Comment: Are there some particular assumptions under which you would like this to be true?  I don't see any reason to expect it to be true unless $X$ is compact and the equivalence relation is closed (in particular, I don't see how knowing the fibers are discrete is helpful at all).

Comment: For example, one of possible assumptions could be that $\varphi$ is a projection under (finite) group action.

Comment: E.g. closed equivalence relation is ok, but X could be non-compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true if $\varphi$ is the quotient by an action of a finite group $G$ on $X$.  Indeed, in that case, for any closed set $C\subset X$, $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(C))=\bigcup_{g\in G} gC$ is a finite union of closed sets and hence closed.  More generally, the quotient map by the action of a compact group is closed, though the proof is more complicated.

The following counterexamples may also be instructive.  First, consider $X=[0,1]\times\{0\}\cup [0,1)\times\{1\}$ and $Y=[0,1]$, with $\varphi$ the projection.  Then $\varphi$ is an open quotient map of Hausdorff spaces with finite fibers, but $\varphi$ is not closed ($\varphi([0,1)\times\{1\})$ is not closed).

Second, consider $X=[0,1]\times \{0,1\}$ and let $\varphi$ be the quotient by the equivalence relation $(t,0)\sim(t,1)$ for $t\in [0,1)$.  Then $\varphi$ is an open quotient map on a compact Hausdorff space with finite fibers, but it is not closed ($\varphi([0,1]\times\{0\})$ is not closed).

Third, let $X=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\cup\{(\infty,\infty)\}$, topologized as a subset of $[-\infty,\infty]\times[-\infty,\infty]$.  Let $\mathbb{Z}$ act on $X$ by $(n,(x,y))\mapsto (n+x,y)$ (where $n+\infty=\infty$ for all $n$) and let $\varphi:X\to Y=X/\mathbb{Z}$ be the quotient map.  Then $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff and $\varphi$ is the quotient by the action of a group and has closed discrete fibers, but $\varphi$ is not closed ($\varphi(\{0\}\times\mathbb{R})$ is not closed).